# Cant retrieve $_POST inside page, just header

Tags: posts, pages

Here is the full code:

http://codepad.org/BpqQ3Xm0

Line 113, I am sending $_POST["popust"] ; And I use it to compare value at the top -line 33. But if I want to echo it, print_r, var_dump, inside page - after get_header();, I am getting empty results. Even if i define some variable at the top, i cant call it inside page as its always empty. 
Anyway, I need this $_POSTto test validation, but struggling to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Were you ever able to sort this out? I'm having the same issue. Best I can tell, somewhere after the save_post fires the $_POST data for that post/form gets trashed.

fwiw, what I'm considering doing is doing my validation and then using a post_meta as a proxy for $_POST. In other words, if validation fails write my form data to some post_meta. And whenever I'm displaying that form, I always first check for "error data".

To me this feel dirty and "hacky" but I'm also pretty sure it would work. After all, what is $_POST but an array. I don't think I want to store the whole $_POST in a post_meta, just the stuff I need for that form. And after all, that's where the form data is going to end up anyway...in post_meta.

Actually, now that I think about it, it might just be a matter of storing the validation error msg in post_meta and making sure a post isn't published unless the post_meta for error is blank. In other words, ! errors == OK to publish. Errors == Don't allow publish.

Storing "bad data" is fine. WP seems to be handling the storing just fine :) The real issue is error msgs AND preventing posts with "bad data" from being published.

What do you think?

FYI - This approach does in fact work, at least for custom post types and simple-ish forms. (It might work for more robust things but I'm kinda in proof of concept mode.)

The only thing I have to resolve is that WP will display "Post Published" (at the top of the page in a yellow box) even though I've bumped the post_status back to draft when the validation method(s) hit something that doesn't pass.

I'm pretty sure there's a way to suppress that, but I haven't looked into it just yet.